# get the tag of a git branch

Tags: git

I'm currently trying, for fun, to build a package management system (similar to apt / yum / zypper, etc...) using the git revision system, and I' searching for a way to know what is the latest stable version of the current branch.

Example : the Linux kernel

I would like to know, from  the 3.18 branch, what is the latest tag (currently "3.18.9"), and, if possible, the commit identification code (currently "d1034e83796a0433194f67c2a8c4abf0f6138b01").

How can I do it without having to downloading all the repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a simpler variant, but the following will get you the commit SHA-1 of the last commit to the `master` branch:

```
git show -s origin/master
```

(assuming your remote is called `origin` in your local repository).

If you only want the commit,

```
git show -s origin/master | awk 'NR == 1 { print $2 }'
```

To make sure you're getting the latest information, you should `git fetch` beforehand. Referring to `origin/master` means this works regardless of the state of your local `master`, so you don't need to `git pull`.

You can't use `git` locally without cloning the repository you're interested in, but you can limit the amount of data copied by using `--depth` and `--branch` options to `git clone`; for example

```
git clone --branch linux-3.18.y --depth 5 https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git
```

to clone the last five history entries in the `linux-3.18.y` branch of the stable kernel tree. This is called a shallow clone and has a number of limitations; see [the git clone documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html) for details.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without having to fetch the repository?

Comment: Just drop the `git fetch && ` part; that was just to ensure you're really getting the latest commit.

Comment: What's `kernel318` on your system?

Comment: I'm still new at using git. I have created my current git repository with `git init && git remote add -t v3.18 kernel318 git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git`. Probably not the good way, but it didn't show any error when I used it ^^"

Comment: OK, so that means you haven't yet fetched any information from the remote tree; therefore `git` can't give you any history or commit identifiers etc. Generally speaking when working from a remote repository you'd start by cloning it; see my updated answer for an example.